Hydration Error and Locale Headers Issue with Next.js 15 and Next-Intl
I'm working on a Next.js 15 project that utilizes the next-intl library for internationalization. I’m encountering two primary issues:

Hydration Error
I’m receiving a hydration error that states:


Hydration failed because the server-rendered HTML didn't match the client.


Locale Headers Error
Additionally, I’m getting an error related to locale headers:


Error: Route "/[locale]" used headers().get('X-NEXT-INTL-LOCALE'). headers() should be awaited before using its value.


To address the hydration issue, I attempted to use the useEffect hook to defer certain client-side operations, but the hydration error persisted. The code in question involves several components, including the RootLayout which applies the locale and direction dynamically.
I also ensured that next-intl configuration files are set up with middleware.js and i18n.js to manage locales and headers as required.
Code Configuration:
Here are key parts of my configuration for next-intl:
next.config.js

 const nextConfig = {
 timeZone: "Africa/Tunis",
 };
 
const withNextIntl = require("next-intl/plugin")("./i18n.js");
 
 module.exports = withNextIntl(nextConfig);


i18n.js

import { getRequestConfig } from "next-intl/server";
export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => ({
  messages: (await import(`./messages/${locale}.json`)).default,
  timeZone: "Africa/Tunis",
}));


middleware.js

import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
export default createMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "fr", "ar"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
});
export const config = { matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)"] };


app/[locale]/layout.js

import { NextIntlClientProvider } from "next-intl";
import { AppProvider } from "@/context/AppContext";
import { Tajawal } from "next/font/google";
import { getLocale, getMessages } from "next-intl/server";

const tajawal = Tajawal({ subsets: ["arabic"], weight: ["300", "400", "500", "700"] });

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const locale = await getLocale(); 
  const messages = getMessages();
  const direction = locale === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr";
  const fontClassName = tajawal.className;

  return (
    <html lang={locale} dir={direction}>
      <body className={fontClassName}>
        <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
          <AppProvider>{children}</AppProvider>
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



for Hydration Error
try to use suppressHydrationWarning inside html tag at RootLayout.
for the second error i think its related by how to use locale itself,
RootLayout should be like this (i use app router with typescript)
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
}>) {
  const locale = await getAsyncLocale(params);

  return (
    <html
      lang={locale}
      dir={`${locale === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}`}
      suppressHydrationWarning
    >
      <body
        className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}
      >
        <Providers>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

and this is the content of getAsyncLocale
import { Locale, routing } from "@/i18n/routing";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export async function getAsyncLocale(params: { locale: string }) {
  const { locale } = await params; // must be awaited even if it non-promised

  if (!routing.locales.includes(locale as Locale)) {
    notFound();
  }

  return locale;
}


Regarding the Locale Headers Error
Your i18n.js is using the depreacted "locale" (string) as the parameter instead of "requestLocale" (promise):
Deprecated
export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {

Updated
export default getRequestConfig(async ({ requestLocale }) => {
const locale = await requestLocale;

That's what solved the issue for me
